# jQuery money input mask not working in rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-inputmask

I am using the [jquery-inputmask-rails](https://github.com/marcosnogueira/jquery-inputmask-rails) gem.  Ultimately: it is pulling in Robin Herbots' [inputmask jQuery plugin](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask).

As instructed in the `jquery-inputmask-rails` gem, I put this in `application.js`:

```
//= require jquery.inputmask
//= require jquery.inputmask.extensions
//= require jquery.inputmask.numeric.extensions
```

And here are my two masks:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  $('.mask_phone').inputmask({mask: "(999) 999-9999"});
  $('.mask_money').inputmask({alias: 'currency', rightAlign: true, placeholder: "", prefix: '', autoGroup: false, digitsOptional: true});
});
```

As far as usage goes: you should be able to just add the appropriate masking class to the input:

```
<%= f.text_field :some_field, class: "mask_money" %>
```

The issue I am having is that the `mask_phone` mask works, but the `mask_money` does not work at all.

I do notice in the logs it says this:

> TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'e.mask.toString')

The odd thing is that in another project: I did not use the jquery-inputmask-rail gem, but instead brought in the jQuery input mask code into the Vendor directory directly, and it worked.

What am I missing?

Comment: targeting the correct class? `$('.mask_amount_in_cents')`

Comment: sorry typo, I will correct it.

Comment: In this sentence "The issue I am having is that the mask_phone mask works, but the mask_amount_in_cents does not work at all."  should "mask_amount_in_cents"  also be "mask_money"?

Comment: sorry typo I will correct it. should be mask_money.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My gut tells me that the jquery-inputmask-rails gem is not looking at an updated version of Robin Herbots' input mask plugin.

- I removed the gem
- I put the jQuery.inputmask.bundle.js in the `vender` folder.
- In `application.js` I put `//= require jquery.inputmask.bundle.js` and removed the require statements associated to the gem.

And then all my input masks worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i forgot to execute/call

`initializeMasks();`

so dont forget to add this as `script` block in the view or in the `app/views/model/submodel/action.js.erb` file instead of using `<scrip>` right in the view

after that i was able to define and see my `input` field to work just fine using something similiar to this

`<%= f.input :ein, input_html: { data: { mask: '00-0000000' } } %>`

as you can see my mask is not complex just two digits then a dash and then other 7 digits but i hope this helps!